# PHP prepared statement cant't find mistake

Tags: php, mysqli, prepared-statement

Hi I need to have a function what checks if a user already exists in my db.
I need this for specific reasons.
At this point the function always returns false.
Does some one see my mistake in the code?

```
function checkForUserExists($username){
    $mysqli = new mysqli("****", "****", "****", "****");

        if($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE ign = ?")){
        $stmt->bind_param("s", $username);        
        }else{

        }

        $stmt->execute();

        $stmt->bind_result($ign);

    if($ign == $username){
        return false;
    }else{
        return true;
    }
    $stmt->close();

}
```

UPDATE

```
    $mysqli = new mysqli("**", "*", "**", "**");
    $username = "Felipebuy";
   if( $username && $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT ign FROM `users` WHERE `ign` = ?")){
        $stmt->bind_param("s", $username);
        $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->bind_result($ign);   
        $stmt->close();

       if($ign == $username){

        echo "equals";
       }else{
           echo "does not equal eachoter";
       }
    }
```

it only echo's "does not equal eachoter"

Comment: check for errors, s'all I can say

Comment: `if($ign == $username){
        return false;` shouldn't that be "true"? seems like it. if found, true. if not, false. It's only logical.

Comment: `$stmt->close();` code after a return statement will never get executed. Also you maybe want to fetch your data (`$stmt->fetch()`).

Comment: surely also the execute statement and bind_result should be within the `if( $stmt =...`

Comment: @Fred-ii- the logic behind it is that i call the function somewhere else in a if, but it's true it could be a better logical function name n stuff, going to try to return some error's, it's a difficult situation to do that, but I'll try.
thanks for the advice

Comment: totally right @RamRaider

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Made a slight correction, apologies for the delay - had to sleep.

```
    function checkForUserExists( $username=false ){
        $mysqli = new mysqli("****", "****", "****", "****");

        if( $username && $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT `ign` FROM `users` WHERE `ign` = ?")){
            $stmt->bind_param( "s", $username );
            $res=$stmt->execute();

            if( $res ){
                $stmt->bind_result( $ign );
                $stmt->fetch();  
                $stmt->close();
                $mysqli->close();

                return $ign === $username;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    $result=call_user_func('checkForUserExists','Felipebuy');
    echo $result ? 'equals' : 'not equal to each other';
```

Comment: I've edited my post with new code form you it still doesn't work.
do you have any other idea's?

Comment: Thankyou, with your answer I was able to get it working.
The only thing what is wrong for my case in your code is that you select all and after you cech if the whole row equals $username.
But thank you verrt much you made me some mysqli structure clear

Comment: well spotted - I forgot totchange that here when I edited it ;/

Answer (score 1):

You select ALL ( * ) in your statement. Unless your table only contains one column this will output several values. If you compare that result ($ign) with a single value ($username), it most likely won't ever return true.